# Unable to deploy Django app to heroku using heroku local

Tags: python, django, heroku, firefox, gunicorn

Novice here.

Trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku and I get an Unable to connect from the Firefox browser (I tried Chrome as well with similar results). I'm having a lot of trouble troubleshooting where exactly the problem is? Heroku local? Gunicorn? Browser Firewall? Django Settings?
[image]
What I have done.

1. Added the django_heroku import to settings.py
   [image]
2. Tried to ensure My browser(Firefox) is not blocking pop-ups etc.
   Firefox -> settings-> Privacy and security -> permissions-> Uncheck Block pop-up windows
   [image]
3. Ensured my app works on with just gunicorn
   I run gunicorn project3.wsgi in my terminal (project3 is the directory for my wsgi file) which works

[image]

[image]

4. I have the same command in my Procfile, uppercase 'P' (web: gunicorn project3.wsgi).
   However when I run the command 'heroku local' The browser opens up on clicking the link, but I get an error. Any assistance would be appreciated.
   I am running commands using windows WSL
   [image: Heroku Local]

Comment: Hello @SopeadeLanlehin as per `Heroku` doc. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#settings-py-changes you have to import `import django_heroku` at top of your `settings.py` and this `django_heroku.settings(locals())` should at the bottom of your `settings.py` so it will wrap all the `settings` configuration for `Heroku`

Comment: Thank you soo much Ankit. I will try that right away and get back to you!! Been struggling with this for waaay too long

Comment: Hello Ankit. No luck. Doesn't matter where the import django_heroku is (I moved it to the top). STill doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `0.0.0.0` is valid IP, it is not usable as a real IP address.

You can use either http://localhost:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000/

> In the Internet Protocol Version 4, the address 0.0.0.0 is a
> non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or
> non-applicable target. This address is assigned specific meanings in a
> number of contexts, such as on clients or on servers.

You can read more about 0.0.0.0 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

Comment: Thank you Sumithran. I read about it from you link. No idea how to change it though (I am very new to deploying and dealing with ip addresses etc.). Hope it isn't too presumptuous. But is there a command to change the address? Or do I need to do a bunch of other things for that. Thanks

Comment: Hello @SopeadeLanlehin You can change the port by typing this command `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:5000` you can specify any port you want.

Comment: @SopeadeLanlehin you don't have to change anything, just run `heroku local` and go to http://localhost:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000/, that's it

Comment: I feel so silly. Ok so you run it in your terminal. But don't click the link it provides (http://0.0.0.0:5000). Instead go to the (127.0.0.1:5000). Got it. That works. Ok now, all that is left is to have an actual url listed there. A steep learning curve for me, but I'll get there. Thanks Sumithran!